# file_get_contents not loading the full source code because parts are loaded on page load

Tags: javascript, php, onload

I want to copy the entire source code of an external website to a file for later modification and analysis.  But a table on domain.com/stats is not static HTML but is build by JavaScript and loaded on page load.

The problem is that it thus is not included in the source code!

This is what my code look like right now:

```
$txt = file_get_contents('http://domain.com/stats');
file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . '/statistic/stats.html', $txt);
```

Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you scan `$txt` for dynamically loaded content, you could perform further `file_get_contents` requests to retrieve those contents as well and store those along with the original content.

Answer (score 0):

Only way you are going to get the JavaScript to run is if you use a headless browser to retrieve and execute the scripts.